# SUM and MAX function in SQL with multiple group by clause causes issue

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, subquery, max

I have the following table:

| id | student | period | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Q1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | Q1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Q2 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | Q3 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | Q1 | 7 |
| 6 | 3 | Q1 | 8 |
| 7 | 3 | Q2 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 | Q2 | 1 |
| 9 | 3 | Q3 | 0 |
| 10 | 3 | Q3 | 0 |
| 11 | 4 | Q1 | 1 |
| 12 | 4 | Q3 | 9 |

I want to know that in which period which student has the most points in total.

---

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(SUM(point)) score,
    student,
    `period`
FROM table1
GROUP BY student, `period`
```

it gives the following error:

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

---

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT
    `period`,
    student,
    MAX(p) score
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(point) p,
        student,
        `period`
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY student, `period`
) t1
GROUP BY `period`
```

it gives the following result:

| period | student | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | 1 | 15 |
| Q2 | 1 | 5 |
| Q3 | 1 | 9 |

The periods and their max points are good, but I always have the first student id.

---

**Expected output:**

| period | student | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | 3 | 15 |
| Q2 | 2 | 5 |
| Q3 | 4 | 9 |

On top of that. If there is more than one student with the highest points, I want to know all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use max window function as the following:

```
WITH sum_pt AS
(
    SELECT student, period,
    SUM(point) AS st_period_pt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY student, period
),
max_sum as
(
  SELECT *,
    MAX(st_period_pt) OVER (PARTITION BY period) AS max_pt_sum
  FROM sum_pt
)
SELECT student, period,  st_period_pt
FROM max_sum
WHERE st_period_pt = max_pt_sum
ORDER BY period
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/p-rA9n3i).

Answer (score 2):

Try with window functions:

- `SUM`, to get the total points for each <student, period> pair
- `ROW_NUMBER`, to rank points for each period

Then you can select where ranking = 1 to get your highest points for each period.

```
WITH students_with_total_points AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(point) OVER(PARTITION BY student, period) AS total_points 
    FROM tab
), ranking_on_periods AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY period ORDER BY total_points DESC) AS rn 
    FROM students_with_total_points
)
SELECT id, student, period, total_points
FROM ranking_on_period
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I don't get it. 
If I execute the subquery I'll get the single most points. But I need to sum the points before selecting the max of it.

Comment: What's the expected output? @Simon-VargaCsaba

Comment: Well, if there is more than one students with the highest points in a period I wan to know all of them...

Comment: This should reflect your current expected output now.

Comment: That's ok. I'm not sure if the `id` is needed at the last SELECT statement.

Comment: You're right, that's extra, you can remove it from the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could use left join as follows :

```
select t1.period, t1.student, t1.score
from (
    select student, period, score
    from (
        select student, period, SUM(point) as score 
        from table1 s
        group by student, period
    ) as s
    group by period, student
) as t1
left join (
    select student, period, score
    from (
        select student, period, SUM(point) as score 
        from table1 s
        group by student, period
    ) as s
    group by period, student
) as t2 on t1.student = t2.student and t1.score < t2.score
where t2.score is null;
```

This query will list also students and their periods if there scores is 0, you can excludes them by adding where close in t1 and t2 temp tables.